# Управление двусторонней печатью принтера

Tags: браузер, печать

На сайте формируется несколько документов для печати. Некоторые из этих документов должны печататься двусторонней печатью, а некоторые только на одной стороне.

Есть ли возможность управлять этим процессом при помощи программы, т.е. человек просто жмет на кнопку "Распечатать все" и каждый из документов печатается в нужном виде? Что для этого требуется?

P.S. Принтер, само собой, поддерживает двустороннюю печать.

Comment: Уточните, кто занимается печатью, клиент из браузера или у вас есть принт-сервер?

Comment: Клиент из браузера

Comment: Конечно, можно просто показывать человеку какие документы двусторонние, чтобы он сам  управлял принтером. Но если это можно автоматизировать, то лучше это сделать.

Comment: Я абсолютно не разбираюсь в этом вопросе, но похоже нужен будет какой-то сервис,  способный просматривать  очередь печати и передавать принтеру признак того, что документ нужно печатать с двух сторон... Поправьте меня, пожалуйста, если  я не права.